# Checking specific map value properties (predicate) with Hamcrest (Java 8)

Tags: junit4, hamcrest, assertj

With AssertJ I can check that Map has key with referencing value satisfying specific `Consumer`:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public static class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

@Test
public void x() {
    Map<String, User> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key", new User(123, "Random Hacker"));
    Assertions.assertThat(map).hasEntrySatisfying("key", __ -> {
        Assertions.assertThat(__.getName()).isEqualTo("Random Hacker");
    });
}
```

Is it possible to check conditions for specific `Map` value for given key (along with key/value presence) with Hamcrest?

**NOTE** `public SELF hasEntrySatisfying(K key, Consumer<? super V> valueRequirements)` has been added to AspectJ as of v3.6.0 (2016-11-21).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Using Hamcrest for testing - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Hamcrest/article.html#exercise-using-hamcrests-built-in-matchers) there is a hasEntry method available in hamcrest.

Its usage is as [such](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasEntry(K,%20V)):

```
org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(myMap, org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasEntry("bar", "foo"))
```

If you need a more general matcher there is [this](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasEntry(org.hamcrest.Matcher,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)) method:

Example:

```
assertThat(myMap, hasEntry(equalTo("bar"), equalTo("foo")))
```

Any of the many matchers from Hamcrest or your own custom matcher can be used instead of "equalTo".

Comment: I am aware of `hasEntry(K key, V value)`. It involves `equals()` on `key` and `value`. In case of complex values I don't have explicit `equals` and can only check some properties of value. My question may not require this directly but example + `hasEntrySatisfying` signature show the case.